# Hibernate Cascade ALL vs. PERSIST causes collection not associated exception

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, cascade

i couldn't quite find a good answer for this, here's what i'm wondering

i am running into a bug in the following situation:  I have a few tables in my gwt app, equipment_checkouts, equipment_checkins, equipment_types, events, and equipment_types_events_xref.  The checkouts and checkins are there to keep history of everything that's been checked in and out.

Now, here's what i'm running into.

whenever I checkout or checkin an equipment type, a new Equipment checkout/checkin is created just fine.  However, if the Cascade type in the EquipmentCheckout class for the EquipmentType/Event is set to ALL the xref_table reference is created fine, if the Cascade Type is set to anything but ALL i get the exception "Collection is not associated with any session".

When i go to delete if the cascade type is set to All, almost anything that's assigned to an event gets deleted.

I clearly am not understanding the correct way to setup the Cascading - If anybody can help me fix this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

edit: all i want to do, when the equipment_type or event is deleted i want it to wipe out all of the checkout/checkin history - that's... really it, but without setting everything to CascadeType.ALL it throws an exception

Comment: Please post your mappings and the code you are using for persisting the entities

Answer (score 0):

So, as I mentioned from this words:

> edit: all i want to do, when the equipment_type or event is deleted i want it to wipe out all of the checkout/checkin history - that's... really it, but without setting everything to CascadeType.ALL it throws an exception

You have equipment_type assosiated with, for example, equipment_checkouts as OneToMany:

```
public class EquipmentType {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipmentType")
  private List<EquipmentCheckout> checkouts

}

 public class EquipmentCheckOut {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private EquipmentType equipmentType;

}
```

As I understand you the right way you should use `orphanRemoval = true` in `@OneTomany` annotation and from another side `optional = false` to point that EquipmentCheckOut parent can not be null. I'm not sure, but maybe you should use `cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}` instead of `CascadeType.ALL` to prevent bug situation if an `EquipmentType` has parent (for e.g. account). So, the result will looks like:

public class EquipmentType {

```
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipmentType",
             cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, cascadeType.REFRESH},
             orphanRemoval = true))
  private List<EquipmentCheckout> checkouts

}

 public class EquipmentCheckOut {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private EquipmentType equipmentType;

}
```

But as Gonzalo Garcia Lasurtegui mentioned you better offer us more info (entities, mappings, etc)